# MUI TextField MaxLength Character Issue

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I have 100000 phoneNumbers to input in MUI TextField multiline, when there upto 10000 phone number working fine, but when there is more than that it cause line break issue

```
<Controller
                    name="contacts"
                    control={control}
                    rules={{
                      required:
                        file !== null || selectedGroups?.length > 0
                          ? false
                          : 'Number Required',
                      pattern: {
                        value: /^([0-9]{10})(,[0-9]{10})*$/,
                        // value: /^((\+(91)[0-9\s]{10}(,\+(91)\d{10})?*)*)+$/,
                        // value: /^((\[0-9\s]{10}(,\d{10})?)*)+$/,
                        message: 'Please enter valid format.',
                      },
                    }}
                    render={({ field }) => (
                      <TextFiled
                        inputRef={toRef}
                        fullWidth
                        InputProps={{
                          onFocus: () => {
                            setFocus('to');
                          },
                          readOnly: csvData ? true : false,
                        }}
                        type="number"
                        multiline
                        minRows={6}
                        maxRows={10}
                        maxLength={1500000}
                        placeholder="Enter mobile number here 1234567890,1234567890,1234567890,1234567890,1234567890,1234567890"
                        {...field}
                        onChange={(e) => {
                          const result = e.target.value.replace(
                            /[^0-9+,]/gi,
                            ''
                          );
                          e.target.value = result;
                          field.onChange(e);
                        }}
                        error={errors.contacts?.message}
                      />
                    )}
                  />
```

[This is the Screen shot like one character in line break and when click backspace it will remove before the text character](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ft9BS.png)

It should accepts atleast 100000 phone numbers